# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createNonBlockingByteArrayParser()

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

All springframework 5.3.18 including spring-webflux
reactor-netty 1.1.1
reactor-core 3.5.1

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/messages")
public class WsmessageController {

    @Autowired
    private WSMessageService wSMessageService;

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Wsmessage> findAllWSMessages() {
        List<Wsmessage> wsMessages = wSMessageService.findAllWSMessages("SELECT u FROM Wsmessage u");
        System.out.println("SERVER GET ALL MESSAGES = " + wsMessages);
        return wsMessages;
    }

public Flux<Message> findAll()
{
   Flux<Message> messages = webClient.get().uri("/messages").retrieve().bodyToFlux(Message.class);
 return messages;
}

List<Message> messagesblock = messages.collectList().block();
```

When in try to consume and REST API with Wpring WebClient it give me the WARN and get blocked

> WARN  [reactor.core.Exceptions] (reactor-http-nio-8) throwIfFatal
> detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below::
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createNonBlockingByteArrayParser()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser

12:10:05,521 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13) messages = MonoFlatMapMany

12:10:05,537 INFO  [ma.gov.adii.technicalServices.log.impl.MethodLogger] (default task-15) ma.gov.adii.service.impl.WSMessageServiceImpl.findAllWSMessages([Ljava.lang.Object;@780e9a42) execution time: 9 ms
12:10:05,542 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) SERVER GET ALL MESSAGES = [ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@7c2be9e4, ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@73c8237, ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@2d031860, ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@5cb1a46d, ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@7f7602d6, ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@1c380a35, ma.gov.adii.entities.Wsmessage@294dc1ca]

12:10:05,545 WARN  [reactor.core.Exceptions] (reactor-http-nio-3) throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createNonBlockingByteArrayParser()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
at org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2Tokenizer.tokenize(Jackson2Tokenizer.java:243)
at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:138)
at org.springframework.http.codec.DecoderHttpMessageReader.read(DecoderHttpMessageReader.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readToFlux$16(BodyExtractors.java:219)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readToFlux(BodyExtractors.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$null$3(BodyExtractors.java:115)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$toFlux$5(BodyExtractors.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.body(DefaultClientResponse.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.bodyToFlux(DefaultClientResponse.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$bodyToFlux$4(DefaultWebClient.java:555)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:163)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:245)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195)
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:174)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:431)
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:705)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:195)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:456)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:637)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

12:10:05,546 WARN  [reactor.core.Exceptions] (reactor-http-nio-3) throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createNonBlockingByteArrayParser()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
at org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2Tokenizer.tokenize(Jackson2Tokenizer.java:243)
at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:138)
at org.springframework.http.codec.DecoderHttpMessageReader.read(DecoderHttpMessageReader.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$readToFlux$16(BodyExtractors.java:219)
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readToFlux(BodyExtractors.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$null$3(BodyExtractors.java:115)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.readWithMessageReaders(BodyExtractors.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyExtractors.lambda$toFlux$5(BodyExtractors.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.body(DefaultClientResponse.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.bodyToFlux(DefaultClientResponse.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$bodyToFlux$4(DefaultWebClient.java:555)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:163)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:539)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.java:245)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:195)
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:174)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:431)
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:705)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:195)
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:456)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:637)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependency to your pom.xml file

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>


 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>${jackson.version}</version>
 </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: I add all dependencies mentioned below but same problem: 
                            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.10.2</version>
      
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>2.10.2</version>
   
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.10.2</version>

Answer (score 0):

The problem in JVM of my server when I was using Wildfly 10.
The problem was resolved by upgrading to wildfly 14